# How do I write <?php....?> inside an echo?

Tags: php, codeigniter, echo

I'm using CodeIgniter to insert an image into an empty div tag and I'm having some trouble putting php code within a an echo. I've been trying to figure it out but I just can't seem to get my head around why it's not working.

```
<?php
     echo ('<div class="badge"><img src="<?php echo base_url("images/profiles/badge100.png"); ?>" title="100% on a quiz!" alt="100% on a quiz!"/></div>');
?>
```

I thought using "..." inside of '...' was the right thing to do. But obviously not.
The following is what it's coming out as on the actual HTML page.

```
 <div class="badge">
          <img src="?&gt;&lt;?php echo base_url(" images="" profiles="" badge100.png");="" ?=""><!--?php " title="100% on a quiz!" alt="100% on a quiz!"/-->
 </div>
```

I appreciate your help!

Lewis.

Comment: .. What's preventing you from simply concat'ing the string? `echo "string" . base_url($url) . "more strings";`

Comment: You don't nest `<?php ?>` inside PHP code. Concatenate the string.  `echo '<div......' . base_url(....) . ' title=.....';`

Comment: you dont have to do nested echo, 1 echo is enough

Comment: [The PHP manual on strings....](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski + Daedalus, Just remove the php I tried to put in?

Comment: @EHU-Lewis No, don't just remove the `<?php` You need to close the current open string, concatenate in your function with the dot operator `.` then concatenate on the rest of the string. Follow the pattern in my earlier comment.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Okay i've done it like you said
<img src="' .base_url('images/profiles/badge100.png').  '" title="100% on a quiz!" alt="100% on a quiz!"/> worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use echo() inside echo()? 
You can simply use (variable) in place substitution .

```
<?php
     $base = base_url("images/profiles/badge100.png");

     echo ('<div class="badge"><img src="{$base}" title="100% on a quiz!" alt="100% on a quiz!"/></div>');
?>
```

Comment: This would not work.  Variables inside of single-quoted strings do not evaluate.  I wonder who voted this up.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to break the echo string, additionally I wouldn't use echo with ().
Add values with the dot, use single quotes, so you can use double quotes in html.

```
$a = "apples";
$b = "bananas";
echo '<p class="exampleClass">Hmmm I like '.$b.' and '. $a.' too,</p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use php operator "." simple example is right here

```
<?php 
    echo '<div class="badge"><img src="'. base_url("images/profiles/badge100.png") . '/></div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<?php
 echo ('<div class="badge"><img src="'.base_url("images/profiles/badge100.png").'" title="100% on a quiz!" alt="100% on a quiz!"/></div>');
?>
```